# Custom theme's blueprints not being detected in Admin plugin at all

Tags: grav

Following this example: https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/blueprints/example-page-blueprint

I created my video.yaml file under "user/themes/MYTHEMENAME/blueprints", contents of its file:

```
title: Gallery
'@extends':
    type: default
    context: blueprints://pages

form:
  fields:
    tabs:
      type: tabs
      active: 1

      fields:
        gallery:
          type: tab
          title: Gallery

          fields:
            header.txf:
              type: text
              label: Add a number
              default: 5
              validate:
                required: true
                type: int

            header.sb:
              type: select
              label: Select one of the following
              default: one
              options:
                one: One
                two: Two
                three: Three
```

Cleared all caches, but i still don't see that tab under "/admin/pages" or "/admin/pages/home" advanced tab. What's wrong? Is it bug?

**UPDATED INFO**

"user/themes/MYTHEMENAME/MYTHEMENAME.yaml":

```
enabled: true
dropdown:
  enabled: true
```

"user/config/site.yaml":

```
title: domain.org
author:
  name: Name
  email: 'email@mail.com'
metadata:
    description: 'analytical news feed'
    generator:
```

Tried to put them under "user/blueprints/pages/" - still not EFFECT! Why such an easy tasks is too complicated in grav...

Comment: Just tested it and your blueprint is correct. Are you sure you created your theme correctly? Or are you sure you have a template named video.html.twig? Grav will look for a template with a matching name, so this tab will only be displayed on the pages that use the template "video"

Comment: Yes, i have video.html.twig

Comment: Also, I don't understand your last phrase, the tab will appear alongside content / options / advanced tabs and will be named Gallery. You sure you can't see it on the page that use the video.html.twig template?

Comment: I can't for sure. Maybe there's issue with my theme yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blueprint is correct, it works on my side.

You said you don't see that tab under "/admin/pages" or "/admin/pages/home". This is not how a blueprint works, blueprint is only available  for its page template. You didn't mention any sample paths of your page so it seems your page use a different template.

If your blueprint is `user/themes/yourtheme/blueprints/video.yaml`, it is only available for the pages which use `video` template, for example `user/pages/home/video.md`. Your blueprint will not available to all pages on the site.

Similar to modular template, you need to put your blueprint in `modular` folder: `user/themes/yourtheme/blueprints/modular/video.yaml`, and your modular page needs to use that template as well `user/pages/home/_myvideo/video.md`